# How to change lower case am/pm on the menu bar to uppercase?

Tags: macos

[image]

I find the time shown on the menu bar on mavericks a bit annoying. It's not perfect. The "AM/PM" is now shown in lowercase after upgrade to OS X 10.9 Mavericks. Back in the previous versions of OS X, it was displayed in uppercase.

**Is there a way change the lowercase am/pm to uppercase**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since my system is german, I'm not 100% sure, but try this:

- go to 'Language & Region' in the System Preferences

[image: Language & Region]

- open 'Advanced Options'

[image: Advanced Options]

- go to tab 'Time' and see if you can customize the way it's displayed

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Go into System Preferences -> Language & region, click on the button labeled "Advanced…"  in the lower right, select the tab labeled "Times" and and then enter AM / PM as the abbreviations for Before / After noon in the lower left text fields.